# complex javascript object will not JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create a JavaScript object to convert to a json to send via ajax

```
$("#submitList").on("click", function(){
    var Book = { book : new Array()};
    var sheetsArray = new Array();
    var preBook

     $(".add-list").each( function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            var BookName = $(this).val().split("+|+");
            var table = $(this).parents("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").find('table');

            var objDetails = {
                    Name : $(table).attr("id"),
                    FirstRow : $(table).find(".FirstRow").is(":checked"),
                    emailcol : $(table).find(".emailcol option:selected").val()}

            if(preBook != BookName[0]){
                preBook = BookName[0];
                sheetsArray = new Array();  
                sheetsArray[BookName[1]] = objDetails ;
            }else{
                sheetsArray[BookName[1]] = objDetails ;
            }
            Book.book[BookName[0]] = sheetsArray;
        }
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(Book));
    console.debug(JSON.stringify(Book));
})
```

but on the output of JSON.stringify(Book) all I get is

```
{"book":[]}
```

but the object looks like this

```
Object (
  [book] => Array(
    [Book3] => Array(
        [1-State.csv] => Object (
            [Name] => 1-State.csv
            [FirstRow] => true
            [emailcol] => 2
        )
        [2-country.csv] => Object (
            [Name] => 2-country.csv
            [FirstRow] => false
            [emailcol] => 2
        )
    )
    [Book1.2] => Array(
        [0-Sheet1.csv] => Object (
            [Name] => 0-Sheet1.csv
            [FirstRow] => true
            [emailcol] => 2
        )
    )
  )
)
```

I am not sure what the problem is, other then I think it maybe a problem with using array but from what I understand about stringify it should do both arrays and objects

Comment: do `alert(JSON.stringify(Book));` just after `Book.book[BookName[0]] = sheetsArray;`

Comment: You can find an explanation and solution in the duplicate. Just briefly here: `JSON.stringify` only considers numerical properties of an array, but you seem to be using non-numerical properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using `Book.book` as a key value pair, not as an array so defind `book` as an object instead of as an array

```
var Book = { book : {}};
```

Comment: I just changed all the 'new Array()' to 'new Object()' and it worked like a charm, thanks